# How to delete default themes

Tags: themes, customization, theme-twenty-seventeen

Is it possible to delete the default Themes (Twenty Eleven, Twenty Twelve, Twenty Thirteen …) automatically … or - even better - disable the automatic re-installation on when updating WordPress?

I've read this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114429/should-i-delete-the-default-themes) and i know that many consider it useful to have at least on of this themes. But i never used one of these and just want them gone ;)

Comment: Why do you need to do automatically? Are sure thems ll reinstalled if we update wp? I don't think so. for me once it deleted ll never appeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach is to delete the default themes using ftp or your control panel file-manager once you have your site up and running.

These themes will not be re-installed when you update Wordpress, and will not show up in your update notifications.

I usually **keep the TwentySixteen theme** on the system as this is the fallback theme in case you have problems with your installed theme.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do to "automate" the process to delete themes is to use WP-CLI, namely the [`delete`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/theme/delete/) command. like so:

`$ wp theme delete twentytwelve`