# Prevent WordPress from automatically installing a new theme each year

Tags: customization, themes

Is there a setting for new disabling new yearly themes?  Each year my WordPress installation automatically installs a new theme which I then delete.  For example, this year the theme [Twenty Twenty-Two](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentytwentytwo/) was installed.

I already have a theme I like and I'm never going to want to use the newest theme of the year.  I'm hoping there is some way to prevent WordPress from automatically installing these new themes in the future.

A few years ago somebody asked [How to delete default themes?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/310286/how-to-delete-default-themes) I already know how to delete the themes and they never got an answer about how to prevent them from being installed to begin with. There is also the question [Should I delete the default themes?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114429/should-i-delete-the-default-themes) which is related, but doesn't actually answer my question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Looking through some resources, I found [this track ticket which discusses the same topic](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/49056). It seems the following will stop it, add it to your *wp-config.php*:

```
define('CORE_UPGRADE_SKIP_NEW_BUNDLED', true);
```

Comment: I updated my config with this setting and confirmed that the site doesn't break.   I have a second WordPress site that hadn't been updated in a year.  I put this setting in for it, and then performed the updates. No new themes were installed. Since new themes are usually installed with these updates, I can confirm that this setting works.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks for confirming and happy that it solved the issue!